# Loopback ACL if owner is not set

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have an app where you can start to make an order without being authenticated and just register before the last step of the payment. It means that my model order is first created and updated without any owner in order to save the data, and then userId is attached at the end of the process.

How can I create an ACL that allow :

everyone to execute if there is no owner
if there is a owner, only the owner can execute everything on it.
For the moment, with some orders have userId null, and some others have it set, I have 401 if I want to list my orders for example for the authenticated user.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished to succeed by creating a new custom role, called `softOwner`. In case someone need it, here is the code :

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var Role = app.models.Role;
  Role.registerResolver('softOwner', function(role, context, cb) {
    function reject(err) {
      if(err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, false);
    }

    var userId = context.accessToken.userId;
    if (!userId) {
      return reject(); // do not allow anonymous users
    }
    context.model.findById(context.modelId, function(err, model) {
      if(err || !model) {
        reject(err);
      }

      if(model.userId) {
        // if there is an owner, check that it is the right owner

        (model.userId == context.accessToken.userId) ? cb(null, true) : reject();
      } else {
        // if there is no owner, authorize
        cb(null, true);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

And then just add it in the ACLs :

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "WRITE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "softOwner",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
},
```

Comment: How do you set model.userId? Did you create a property in the model, and then middleware to assign it on create? Or does loopback do this for you with the $owner property? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970066/loopback-io-model-acl-principalid-owner

Comment: You just need to set a belongs to relation with the user model and Loopback  handle it !

Comment: Yes, but it has limited functionality, like you need to specify the post id in the request. GET all records does not work with permissions, neither batch updates.